# Why is rows.count failing?

Tags: excel, vba

I have been using rows.count for a long time but all of a sudden all my macros (which worked for a years) are saying "Compile Error:  Method or data member not found".

I use this in many of my macros:

```
Dim LastRow as Long
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

IE this macro which basically selects A1.currentregion:

```
Sub Select_Range_Auto()
'Automatically selects all the cells based on top row and column A from top left to bottom right.

Dim answer As Integer
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Endcolumn As Long
Dim rng As Range

LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Endcolumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Set rng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRow, Endcolumn))

rng.Select
End Sub
```

I've used this code for a long time but today I started getting the compile error mentioned above.

All my macros are getting this error today when I've never gotten it before!  Some of these macros are macros I've used for years and HAVE NOT CHANGED.  It highlights the ".count" part of Rows.Count when it errors!

Please help!

Comment: Do you have a module, sub, function or public variable called `Rows` or `Count`?  It would also help if you added the parent sheet to all the range objects: `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range...` or `Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells`  At least add `ActiveSheet.` in front of any range object. which includes `Rows.Count`

Comment: Two close votes on a 12-min old question?  Why?  It looks like a perfectly valid and on-topic post - has code, and a clearly-stated problem statement.

Comment: @TimWilliams "It's seeking debugging help but needs more information. The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem**. (Emphasis Mine).  With the current verbiage/code we can only guess as to the problem.

Comment: What information would you be looking for to further debug the provided error on a line such as `LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`?  What variable declarations or other items are missing here?  Your posted guess seems likely to be the cause of the problem, so why not let the OP respond instead of closing?  It seems unreasonable to expect the OP to include the source of their problem such that we can reproduce it - they do not know what the source if the issue is, hence their post.

Comment: @TimWilliams it has not been closed as of yet, and it has been 18 minutes since I asked.  If the OP responds, I will happily vote to reopen if it does get closed, and remove my vote if not yet closed.  My current opinion, and it may be wrong, is that if it takes a shotgun of guesses to find the answer then the question is not specific enough.  Yes I may have been little quick on this one, but the longer the OP takes to respond the more I think I got it correct.

Comment: I had created a module called Rows.  Thank you Scott for your answer.  Changing the name of this module fixed all my macros.  Sorry for the late reply.  I'm at work and should not browse the web more than necessary.

Comment: @SabatinoOgnibene by adding the `ActiveSheet` or better yet the actual worksheet to the parent of the `Rows.Count` ie: `Worksheet("Sheet1").Rows.Count` would have avoided this also.  One should get in the habit of always assigning the parent sheet to any range objects.  There are many other errors that happen when this step is skipped.